# Find multiple adjacent values in container

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I am looking for an algorithm that provides me an iterator to a to be defined number of adjacent equal values inside a STL container.

Something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> values = { 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6 };
auto it = std::adjacent_find(values.begin(), values.end(), 4);
// Here I expect it pointing to the first '8' in above vector
```

Of course adjacent_find does not work this way and is limited to two adjacent values.

Also `search_n` didn't help me, as I do not want to define the specific value I am looking for, just the number of adjacent equal values.

Is there anything from the STL I can use or do I need to define my own algorithm?
A google and stackoverflow search did not bring me any good results. Only this question which is different to what I am trying to do: [How to find the biggest sequence of some number passed like parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436230/how-to-find-the-biggest-sequence-of-some-number-passed-like-parameter)

Comment: Start with `std::equal_range`, perhaps.

Comment: @user58697 But then I need to know the value that occurs multiple times in the vector. I'd liked to specifiy only the minimum length of the sequence of equal but unknown values.

Comment: This is fairly interesting. May I ask what's the use of this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no kind of `consecutive_find()` algorithm in the standard library. I've implemented one for you here (complexity `O(n)`):

```c++
template <class Iter>
Iter consecutive_find(Iter first, Iter last, std::size_t n)
{
    Iter marker(first), lead(first);
    std::size_t count(1);

    while (lead != last)
    {
        lead = std::next(marker);

        while ((lead != last) && (*marker == *lead))
        {
            ++count;
            ++lead;
        }

        if (count == n)
        {
            if ((lead == last) || !(*lead == *marker))
                return marker;

            ++lead;
        }
        marker = lead;
        count = 1;
    }
    return last;
}
```

[***Live Demo***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bd16573cff39276)

Comment: Thanks for providing this implementation, I tested it and it works. I did not define the behavior for n == 1 or n == 0, but I think naturally the first element should be returned. So I added `if (n <= 1) return first;` before the while loop.

Comment: I just realized, that it does not work as expected all the time. For n == 3 used on my example vector it returns the iterator to the first 6. But I would expect it to return the iterator to the first 8. But I guess I should have made that clearer in my question. If I replace `if (count == n)` with `if (count >= n)` it works as expected.

Comment: @MinusBrain My code was buggy when I first posted it. The final version is in my most recent edit on Codereview - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70132

Comment: The final version still has the behavior that it returns an iterator to the first '6' when you ask for three consecutive values. My expectation would be to return an iterator to the first '8' as 4 consecutive '8's imply 3 consecutive '8's. Replace ´if (count == n)´ with ´if (count >= n)´ and it works.

Comment: @MinusBrain Ok, then the check `count == n` should be `count >= n`. You were right. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of the functionality you were asking for. It might not be the fastest one, but it works:

```
template<class InputIt>
InputIt repetition_find(InputIt first, InputIt last, size_t repetitions)
{
    std::vector<int> temp;
    std::adjacent_difference(first, last, std::back_inserter(temp));
    temp.front()=0;

    int count=0;
    std::for_each(temp.rbegin(), temp.rend()
               , [&](auto& a) { if(a==0) a = ++count; else {a=++count; count=0;}} );

    auto diff =  std::find_if(temp.begin(), temp.end()
                            , [&](auto a) {return a>=repetitions;} ) - temp.begin();
    return std::next(first, diff);
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/402cdfeea87d6a17)

---

Here is the idea:

1. Construct the adjacent difference (and set the first element to 0). Given your starting vector

   ```
   9   9   8   8   8   8   7   7   6   6   6
   ```

   this yields

   ```
   0   0  -1   0   0   0  -1   0  -1   0   0
   ```
2. Now start from the back and count the 0's as long you don't find a non-zero value. In that case reset the counter. This gives:

   ```
   2   1   4   3   2   1   2   1   3   2   1
   ```
3. Next, use `std::find_if` to search for a number which is larger than the number of repetitions (which is `4` here), get the position of this value, add it to the inputted iterator `first` and return the result.

Comment: Thanks, this also works. I had to replace the `auto&` and `auto` within the lambda expressions with ints though. Maybe a compiler thing? Using Visual studio 2013 (v120) toolchain.

Comment: Yes, for generic lambdas you need at least the `Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2013 CTP`. You can easily upgrade to that, see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41151).

Comment: By the way, using first `auto` and next `auto&` is also a bit inconsistent. Here probably `auto const&` is best for general data types, whereas `auto` should be used when primarily fundamental types are used ... just as in normal function parameter passing.

Answer (score 0):

Heres another implementation.

```
template<class Iter>
Iter adjacent_find_n(Iter first, Iter last, std::size_t n, std::size_t offset)
{
  if( first == last )
    return last;

  if( offset > 1 ){
    if(!(*first == *(first - 1))) {
      offset = 1;
    }

    if( offset == n ){
      return first-(n-1);
    }
  }

  return adjacent_find_n(++first, last, n, ++offset);
}

template<class Iter>
Iter adjacent_find_n(Iter first, Iter last, std::size_t n)
{
  return adjacent_find_n(first, last, n, 1);
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/927cc4f4d5656e28)